# When should I put a bounty on a question?

Tags: support

Just wondering if anyone has looked at the data for this site to get an Idea of when would be the best time to bounty a question. Relevance is for the goal of maximising the number of views on the given question.

What are the high traffic days?

Answer (score 2):

A casual look over the traffic stats suggests that the busiest days are weekdays, and especially days in the middle of the working week. Tuesday and Wednesday seem to be the busiest days of all.